# Application doesn't load when Bluetooth Connection thread is called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling, bluetooth

I am making an Android application that is supposed to connect to an Arduino HC-06 module.

I have looked at the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-bluetooth-devices) and have tried to get it working with the provided code.

However when I try to run the code on my Samsung A32 5G all of the views fail to load (blank screen), the connection isn't established and I get the following output from Logcat:

```
2021-11-04 10:25:32.798 15490-15546/com.example.carremote D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.
```

I have looked up the message and for me it seems to be caused by this code:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            BS = BSS.accept();
            Log.println(Log.INFO,TAG, "[*] Looking for Connection");

            if(BS != null)
            {
                x = new EstablishedBTConnection(BS);
                Log.println(Log.INFO, TAG, "[*] Connection established!");
                x.manageConnection(1);
                BSS.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.println(Log.INFO, TAG, "[*] Connection failed!");
    }
}
```

Specifically by:

```
BS = BSS.accept();
```

I do not know how why this is giving me this message or why the connection fails.

If you need any other pieces of code I can provide them and if this question is a duplicate (I wasn't able to find any similar questions) just write a comment with the link and I will remove it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is the rest of the code that has been requested:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButtonFunctions(); //Functions to manage the Buttons
        bluetoothFunctionality.run(); //Starts the Bluetooth thread
}
```

Constructor for the Bluetooth thread, directly taken from the Android documentation.

```
public BluetoothFunctionality() throws IOException
{
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket
    // because mmServerSocket is final.
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    try {
        // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code.
        tmp = BA.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Socket's listen() method failed", e);

    }
    BSS = tmp;
}
```

The code for EstablishedBTConnection:

```
public class EstablishedBTConnection
{
private BluetoothSocket BS;
public EstablishedBTConnection(BluetoothSocket BS)
{
    this.BS = BS;
}

public int manageConnection(int action)
{
    if(action == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            BS.getOutputStream().write(50);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Share your other piece of code too.

Comment: Where are you executing your Runnable from? Inside of a thread or directly calling run()?

Comment: @cincy_anddeveloper I added the code that you asked for, I am calling run from onCreate().

Comment: @Danish I have added my onCreate() function, do you need any other code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

> However when I try to run the code on my Samsung A32 5G all of the views fail to load (blank screen), the connection isn't established

Probably, the code blocks the UI thread until the Bluetooth connection is established (need more details on how the `run` method is called: is it a `Runnable` implementation? if yes, then how is it executed?). Actually have to be sure that provided code is executed in a new thread. Because if the code is not executed in an additional thread, the UI thread (or it is also called the Main thread) simply does not get the control to draw the UI.
See more details about the Android UI thread in the [official doccumentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads).
One of the rules in the documentation:

> Do not block the UI thread

To deal with the issue the long-running code (Bluetooth connection establishment in the particular case) should be executed in a background thread or in a service. For example, read about [worker threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#WorkerThreads) on the same documentation page.

And about the logcat output

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released.
```

The line

```
BSS.close();
```

is only executed in the case of a successful connection. But all the resources **must** be released in any case. A better approach would be to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements. [Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) or later should be used for that.

And also regarding a connection to an Arduino HC-06 module. Could you, please, provide more details or code? What is a `BSS` variable exactly and how is it initialized? What is the code of `EstablishedBTConnection`?

Comment: I have added the code that you have asked for. BSS is a BluetoothServerSocket, sorry for my bad variable names. Thanks a lot for your help, I will get back to you as soon as I can test it.